# Program to search through a file and find matches with deletion words

Tags: python-3.x

My code doesnt do what it is supposed to. It is meant to search through the text file and print words that match with the deletion words created from removing a letter from a given word

```
import math as m
def check_deletions(str,fd):
    count=0
    for int in range(len(str)):
        delWord=str[:int]+str[int+1:]
        doubleChecker=False
        for i in range(int+1,len(str)-1):
            if delWord==str[:i]+str[i+1:]:
                doubleChecker=True
        if doubleChecker==True:
            doubleChecker=False
        else:
            for line in fd:
                if delWord==line.strip():
                    print(delWord)
    print("Found ",count," deletions")
def main():
    file=open("long-word-list.txt")
    check_deletions("baag",file)
    file.close()
main()
```

Comment: can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: @downshift input: balloon expected output: ballon found 1 deletion

Comment: in `check_deletions` function, you set `count=0`, but no where else do you update the `count` value to anything other than `0`, so it will always output `'Found 0 deletions'`. So wherever you check for the deletion, and it is `True`, increment the `count` with `count += 1`.